# Optimizing Iteration of List and Dictionaries Python

Tags: python, performance

This project's goal is to parse through a large file containing data. I parse that data into a list containing a dictionary. I then do calculations based on that data and optionally plot it for visualization purposes. I use the data for simple calculations to the rewards based on their performance. I wrote this so that each worker mining to a pool will be rewarded fairly. This allows multiple people to mine on the same account for quicker payout times.

#### Saved data file example:

`Worker_Data.Data:`

```
Data={'pool_current_hashrate': '100215904', 'pool_average_hashrate': '61640734', 'pool_reported_hashrate': '78165786', 'current_hashrate_alex147': '47721859', 'average_hashrate_alex147': '35791394', 'reported_hashrate_alex147': '36895352', 'current_hashrate_henry147': '52494045', 'average_hashrate_henry147': '25849340', 'reported_hashrate_henry147': '41354162', 'time_stamp': '1620751617', 'eth': '0.008999485617836284', 'zil': '4.654624711084'}
Data={'pool_current_hashrate': '100215904', 'pool_average_hashrate': '61640734', 'pool_reported_hashrate': '78337185', 'current_hashrate_alex147': '47721859', 'average_hashrate_alex147': '35791394', 'reported_hashrate_alex147': '36890956', 'current_hashrate_henry147': '52494045', 'average_hashrate_henry147': '25849340', 'reported_hashrate_henry147': '41509445', 'time_stamp': '1620751678', 'eth': '0.008999485617836284', 'zil': '4.654624711084'}
```

Note: there can be as few as 1 miner or as many as the pool allows, each one specifies the current, average, and reported hash rate of the mining rig.

I parse this file which contains tens of thousands of these lines to calculate how much 'work' each miner has done in the time between payouts and then calculate their take of the change in balance. Each line is a separate dictionary in a list.

### Code:

```
from ast import literal_eval

PATH = "A:\\Python Project\\ezil_api\\Data\\" # path of data file
WORKER_SPLIT = 0.50  # used if start balance is not 0


def make_file(name, config_dict, type_conf, path=PATH):
    with open(path + name + "." + type_conf, "a+") as file:
        for keys, values in zip(config_dict.keys(), config_dict.values()):
            file.write(f"{keys}={values}\n")


def read_data(path, file_name):
    data = []
    with open(path + file_name, "r+") as config:
        lines = config.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            line = line[line.find("=") + 1:]
            line_data = literal_eval(line)
            data.append(line_data)
    return data


def eval_data():
    workers = []
    start_balance_eth = 0
    start_balance_zil = 0
    balance_eth = []
    balance_zil = []
    balance_delta_eth = []
    balance_delta_zil = []
    delta_eth_range = [0]
    time = []
    time_delta = []
    balance_workers_eth = {}
    balance_workers_zil = {}
    hashrate_workers = {}
    integral_worker = {}
    worker_percentage = {}
    b = {}
    odd = 0
    even = 0
    hashrate_pool = []
    balance_eth_delta = []
    total_integral = []
    temp_integral = 0

    files_workers = read_data(path=PATH, file_name="Worker_Data.Data")

    from time import time as t

    for worker_data in files_workers:
        index = files_workers.index(worker_data)

        worker_list_temp = [worker_temp[17:] for worker_temp in worker_data.keys() if "average_hashrate_" in worker_temp]

        for worker in worker_list_temp:
            if worker not in workers:
                workers.append(worker)
                hashrate_workers[worker] = []
                balance_workers_eth[worker] = 0
                balance_workers_zil[worker] = 0
                integral_worker[worker] = []
                worker_percentage[worker] = []
                b[worker] = []

        current_balance_eth = float(worker_data["eth"])
        current_balance_zil = float(worker_data["zil"])
        current_time = int(worker_data["time_stamp"])

        for worker in workers:
            current_worker_in_keys = False
            for keys in worker_data.keys():
                if worker in keys:
                    current_worker_in_keys = True
            if current_worker_in_keys:
                worker_hashrate = worker_data[f"current_hashrate_{worker}"]
                hashrate_workers[worker].append(int(worker_hashrate))
            else:
                hashrate_workers[worker].append(0)

        hashrate_pool.append(float(worker_data["pool_current_hashrate"]))

        if index > 0:
            if current_balance_eth > balance_eth[-1]:
                delta_eth = current_balance_eth - balance_eth[-1]
                balance_delta_eth.append(delta_eth)
            else:
                balance_delta_eth.append(0)
            if current_balance_zil > balance_zil[-1]:
                delta_zil = current_balance_zil - balance_zil[-1]
                balance_delta_zil.append(delta_zil)
            else:
                balance_delta_zil.append(0)

            delta_time = current_time - time[-1]
            time_delta.append(delta_time)

        else:
            start_balance_eth = current_balance_eth
            start_balance_zil = current_balance_zil
            balance_delta_eth.append(0)
            balance_delta_zil.append(0)

        balance_eth.append(current_balance_eth)
        balance_zil.append(current_balance_zil)
        time.append(current_time)

    for d_eth, index_temp in zip(balance_delta_eth, range(len(balance_delta_eth))):
        if d_eth != 0:
            delta_eth_range.append(index_temp)

    for worker in workers:
        # if it doesn't have data for balances, it splits it between workers
        if start_balance_zil > 0:
            balance_workers_zil[worker] += start_balance_zil * WORKER_SPLIT
        if start_balance_eth > 0:
            balance_workers_eth[worker] += start_balance_eth * WORKER_SPLIT

        for index in range(len(delta_eth_range)):
            # integral of hashrate
            if index > 0:
                temp_time_delta_list = time_delta[delta_eth_range[index - 1]:delta_eth_range[index]]
                temp_hashrate_list = [hashrate_workers[worker][delta_eth_range[index - 1]:delta_eth_range[index]],
                                      temp_time_delta_list]
                while len(temp_hashrate_list[0]) < len(temp_hashrate_list[1]):
                    temp_hashrate_list[0].append(0)

                temp_hashrate_len = len(temp_hashrate_list[0])
                x = temp_hashrate_list[0]
                y = temp_hashrate_list[1]
                if temp_hashrate_len > 4:
                    # do simpsons integration:
                    # start = (delta x * h[0] + delta x * h[-1])/3
                    # odd = (delta x * h[1] + delta x * h[3]...) * (4/3)
                    # evens = (delta x * h[2] + delta x h[4]...) * (2/3)
                    start = (x[0] * y[0] + x[-1] * y[-1]) * (4 / 3)

                    for i in range(len(temp_hashrate_list)):
                        if ((temp_hashrate_len - 1) > i) and (i > 0):
                            if i % 2:
                                odd += (x[i] * y[i]) * (4 / 3)
                            else:
                                even += (x[i] * y[i]) * (2 / 3)

                    integral = start + even + odd
                    integral_worker[worker].append(integral)
                    even = 0
                    odd = 0

                elif temp_hashrate_len > 1:
                    # do trapezoid integration
                    # delta x/2(h[0] + 2*h[1] + 2*h[2]... + h[-1])
                    trap_integral = ((x[0] * y[0]) + (x[-1] * y[-1]))
                    for i in range(len(temp_hashrate_list)):
                        if ((temp_hashrate_len - 1) > i) and (i > 0):
                            trap_integral += (x[i] * y[i])
                    integral_worker[worker].append(trap_integral)

                elif temp_hashrate_len == 1:
                    # do riemann sum integration
                    # y * delta x
                    riemann_integral = y[0] * x[0]
                    integral_worker[worker].append(riemann_integral)

    for index in range(len(integral_worker[workers[0]])):
        for worker in integral_worker.keys():
            temp_integral += integral_worker[worker][index]
        total_integral.append(temp_integral)
        temp_integral = 0

    for worker in workers:
        for integral_t, worker_integral in zip(total_integral, integral_worker[worker]):
            try:
                worker_percentage[worker].append(worker_integral / integral_t)
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                pass

    for delta in balance_delta_eth:
        if delta != 0:
            balance_eth_delta.append(delta)

    for worker in workers:
        for percentage, delta in zip(worker_percentage[worker], balance_eth_delta):
            balance_workers_eth[worker] += percentage * delta
            b[worker].append(balance_workers_eth[worker])

    def plot():
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        time.sort(reverse=True)
        plt.xlabel = "Delta Balance index"
        plt.ylabel = "ETH Balance"
        plt.title("Index Vs ETH")

        for worker_d in workers:
            temp_x = []
            for index_d in range(len(worker_percentage[worker_d])):
                temp_x.append(index_d + 1)
            x_d = temp_x
            y_d = b[worker_d]
            plt.plot(x_d, y_d, "-", label=f"{worker_d}")

        def plot_ddx():
            d_list = []
            for local_index in range(len(delta_eth_range)):
                if local_index > 0:
                    temp_index = delta_eth_range[local_index]
                    prev_temp_index = delta_eth_range[local_index - 1]

                    delta_eth_temp = balance_eth[temp_index] - balance_eth[prev_temp_index]
                    delta_time_temp = time[temp_index] - time[prev_temp_index]
                    average_hashrate_temp = (sum(hashrate_pool[prev_temp_index:temp_index])) / (
                            temp_index - prev_temp_index)

                    d_list.append(
                        ((delta_eth_temp / delta_time_temp) / average_hashrate_temp) * 1000000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 10)
                    # magic numbers are as follows:
                    # 1000000, convert to per mh/s,
                    # 60*60*24, convert from seconds to days,

            plt.plot(x_d, d_list, "-", label="ETH per 10 Mh/s per day")

        plt.legend()
        plt.show()

    for keys in balance_workers_eth.keys():
        print(keys, balance_workers_eth[keys])

    plot()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    eval_data()
```

Is there any way I can speed this up? Currently, at 22,000 lines it takes about 40 seconds to execute this program. The main section of code that takes up the most time is the part in which I iterate through `files_workers` in the line: `for worker_data in files_workers:` This takes up a large percentage of the time needed based on my testing and peg's a core on my cpu. Is there a more efficient approach to this problem? I appreciate any help/constructive criticism.

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starter, it seems that the code searches for the relevant index of the current `dict` object:

```
for worker_data in files_workers:
    index = files_workers.index(worker_data)
```

but:

1. you can easily use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to avoid this
2. it seems that you only care about whether or not it's the first iteration, so maybe a flag should be enough.

Comment: Thank you, using enumerate speed up my code by more than a factor of 100 and the culprit turned out to be the .index().